# Clarifications on NSConfinementConcurrencyType context as child of a parent context

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

While reading the doc about [`NSConfinementConcurrencyType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/), I read the following

> You cannot use this concurrency type in conjunction with the new
>   nested contexts feature

This sentence is quite weird to me since I can do, for example, within an `NSOperation` subclass like

```
NSManagedObjectContext * localMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType];
[localMOC setParentContext:[self mainContext]];
```

where the `mainContext` can be injected from outside and is of type `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that documentation is **poorly** worded.

What *I think* it means is that you cannot use:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[moc setParentContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
```

Which I have tested previously and it did fail with an error.  YMMV of course as I tested it in iOS 5.x.

That is different than:

```
NSManagedObjectContext * localMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType];
[localMOC setParentContext:[self mainContext]];
```

Which works just fine and is part of the **newer** Core Data design.

There is a subtle difference between the two initializers and the older, historic, initializer is missing some key component to allow parent-child contexts to work properly.

Comment: Hmm, I was pretty sure I have had to change to private queue type a few times because I wanted to add a child context. Pretty sure I was getting strange behaviour or errors about using confined type as a parent. For some reason, these types of errors don't happen every time, but just show up at odd times when you make some change and it detects the issue.

Comment: More than that is that confinement queues expect the context to be accessed and mutated by the thread in which it was created.  If the child MOC were to push changes from a different thread, you are just asking for undefined behavior.

Comment: Nice. Thank you for doing some tests.

Comment: Are you saying that `[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init]` is not the same as `[... initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType]` ?

Comment: Not 100% identical no.  `[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init]` is a thread confined initialization but it does not have the magic dust that allows parent-child to work.  Again, tested in iOS 5.x YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but according to a short test is seems to me that the restriction
on `NSConfinementConcurrencyType`

> You cannot use this concurrency type in conjunction with the new
>   nested contexts feature

applies to the *parent context* and not to the *child context*. So

```
NSManagedObjectContext * localMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType];
[localMOC setParentContext:[self mainContext]];
```

works, as long as `[self mainContext]` has been created with the main or private
queue concurrency type.

Comment: If that is what they meant then it is even more poorly worded than I thought :)  Having said that, I have attached children to a confined MOC before with no ill effect so I don't think that reading is accurate either.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra: Attaching a child to a confined MOC (or default MOC) crashes with `'Parent NSManagedObjectContext must use either NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType or NSMainQueueConcurrencyType.'` in my test, independent of what the type of the child MOC is.

Comment: Interesting.  Time to go find that example or get checked for memory problems.  Thanks for double checking :)

Comment: @MartinR, I see the same behavior. Do you have a solution for this ?